# Best Practice of reading text file in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

What is the best way to read HTML content from a text file and display the content in JSP?  I have placed the text file in the resource folder using spring mvc 3. Normally I do this kind of stuff with Apache commons in struts but believe spring must have provided some utility for this.

I am thinking about reading it in a tag file.  What utility should i use for that?

Comment: This is what I was trying to acheive.
    [Stackoverflow] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022839/how-do-i-load-a-resource-and-use-its-contents-as-a-string-in-spring.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question of why you would want to do this. The return value from a Spring MVC controller method is usually used to resolve a view. The resolved view then becomes the response body. However, you can use the @ResponseBody annotation to make the raw return value the response body.

Comment: I'll try to expand on this later as I don't have time now

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the `@RequestMapping` method. The Key is the return type `ModelAndView`.

You read your text file and get the html that you need, after this, adding the html to the model and then return the a new `ModelAndView` Object.

Here's a sample:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "siteWithResHtml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadSiteWithResHtml(Model model)
{
  String resourceHtml;
  // do your stuff for reading file and assign it to the String
  model.addAttribute("resource_Html", resourceHtml);
  return new ModelAndView("yourJSP", "model", model);
}
```

and in the jsp you can read the value from the model that you forwarded to the jsp, like this:

```
<div>${model.resource_Html}</div>
```

please take notice that the names are match.