# Loading String from file into Spring bean property

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, file-io

In my spring xml file I have a bean:

```
<bean id="config" class="com.example.BeanConfig">
        <property name="description" value="Long Description Here" />
</bean>
```

Instead of defining the long string inline, I want to read the string from description.txt. Is there any way to do this in the xml without writing a Java class to handle it?

I already came across [How do I load a resource and use its contents as a string in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022839/how-do-i-load-a-resource-and-use-its-contents-as-a-string-in-spring) but I am unclear how to get the bean contents into a property value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Spring's property placeholder and ${property_name} see https://dzone.com/articles/properties-spring