# FileNotFoundException exception when reading from a HTML resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath, filenotfoundexception

I try to open and read an HTML file from within class path.

Please find the directory structure in screenshot below

[image]

Inside class `SendEmail` class I want to read that `verification.html` file.

#### Code

When using the code below, it is throwing me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception here:

```
emailContent = readHTMLFile("../emailTemplate/EmailVerificationTemplate/verification.html");
```

The `readHTMLFile` method looks like this:

```
public String readHTMLFile(String path) throws IOException {
    String emailContent = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while ((emailContent = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(emailContent);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

However, when I use an *absolute* path everything is working fine.

I am very new to Java world.
Please help me to fix this .

Comment: what is the readHTMLFile method? Is this a library that you use? Please share your code to understand

Comment: hi @PanagiotisBougioukos added the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `verification.html` looks rather like a "class path resource" than a file...
   (A file is very environment dependent (e.g. thinking of its path/location), whereas a "CPR" we package & supply with our application & can refer to it with a known&fixed (absolute or relative) (class path) address.
2. Nor [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) nor [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) (by default) "includes" anything else from `src/main/java` than `*.java` files. So please move the according files (including structure/packages) to `src/main/resources` (or `src/test/...` accordingly).
3. When the resource is finally in classpath, since spring:3.2.2, we can do that:

   ```java
   String emailBody = org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.
     copyToString(
        new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource(
   "/full/package/of/emailTemplate/EmailVerificationTemplate/verification.html")
        .getInputStream(), 
        /* you must know(!), better: */
        Charset.forName("UTF-8")
   );
   ```

   (..also outside/before spring-boot-application.)

   In spring context, the `Resource` (`Classpath`-, `ServletContext`-, `File`(!)-, `URL`-, ...) can also be "injected", like:

   ```java
   @Value("classpath:/full/package/...")Resource verificationEmailBody
   ```

   ..instead of calling the constructor.

See also:

- [Spring Core#Resources reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources)
- [`Resource` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)
- [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/592355)
- [How do I load a resource and use its contents as a string in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14022839/592355)

---

When you *need to* refer to `verification.html` as a `File`, then please ensure:
It has a distinct (absolute (ok!) or relative (good luck!)) address (in all target environments)!

Answer (score 0):

### Files and resources in Java

Your file is located inside the *classpath*. This is a special location within your source-code (here in package `utils.emailTemplate.EmailVerificationTemplate`). So we call it a *classpath resource* or simply *resource*.

#### Classpath resources

Usually those [*resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) are destined to be published with your code, although they are actually not code.

In the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) you would put them inside the special `src/main/resources` folder, separated from code.

#### Locating and reading resources

Resources are located **relative from *classpath*** using the `classpath:` schema. Since they are part of the sources, package-tree you can also locate them relative to one of your classes.

From your `SendEmail` class, the given template has relative path `../`. So you can instantiate it as `Resource` building the URL using [`this.getClass().getResource(Stirng relativePath)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) from within your `SendEmail` class:

```java
class SendEmail {
    private final String relativePath = "../emailTemplate/EmailVerificationTemplate/verification.html";

    // build the URL for the resource relative from within your class
    public URL getVerificaitonEmailTemplateUrl() {
        URL templateResourceUrl =  this.getClass().getResource(relativePath);
        return templateResourceUrl;
    }

    // load the resource
    public InputStream getVerificaitonEmailTemplateStream() {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath);
        return is;
    }
}
```

Load a resource as input-stream [`getResourceAsStream(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)
using the relative path from inside your class.

Alternative using Spring's special-purpose extension [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html):

```java
    private final String relativePath = "../emailTemplate/EmailVerificationTemplate/verification.html";

    public String loadContentAsFile() {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(relativePath);
        File file resource.getFile();
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }

    public InputStream getContentAsStream() {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(relativePath);
        InputStream is resource.getInputStream();
        return is;
    }
```

Attention: This **reading from a file** works only if your resource is inside the file system. Not if your resource is inside a JAR:

> This implementation returns a File reference for the underlying class path resource, provided that it refers to a file in the file system.

A safer and more robust way to read from the `ClassPathResource` is  `resource.getInputStream()`.

### From InputStream to String

To fix your method, you could simply exchange the `File` related parts to `InputStream`:

```java
public String readHTML(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String emailContent = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while ((emailContent = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(emailContent);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Or even simpler (see Baeldung's tutorial linked below):

```java
String text = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))  // choose the encoding to fit
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Then re-use it to read from any stream (e.g. a `File`, a `Resource`, `ClassPathResource`, even a `URL`). For example:

```java
public String loadTemplate(String relativeResourcePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativeResourcePath)
    String text = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    return text;
}
```

### See also

- Baeldung: [Access a File from the Classpath using SpringBaeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access)
- Baeldung: [Java InputStream to String](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string)